# Can't connect to local IIS on Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, iis, iis-7.5

I am unable to browse to localhost or 127.0.0.1 on my new Windows 8 machine. The World Wide Web Publishing Service is running. I can't telnet to port 80 on 127.0.0.1 or localhost. The firewall service is not running.

Are there other settings I need to check?

Comment: By "can't connect" do you mean it responds with a blank page or that the connection attempt results in an error?

Answer (score 1):

> **Are there other settings I need to check?**

Check the [port number](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149605) to which IIS is bound.

In an elevated command-prompt use `netstat -anb` to see whether anything is listening on port 80.

Comment: I ran netstat -aon and it showed 0:0:0:0:80 for local address pid 4 which was the System process. It's not clear what System is doing with port 80 and why.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check the `portnumber` on which IIS is running or else try `8080` port number